# Update event post meta each day automaticaly

Tags: post-meta, events

Is there any way to update post meta value each day (daily automaticaly) ?

For example my event has started each day at 10pm my current post meta is: **2015-01-01 10:00** next day i should change it to **2015-01-02 10:00** and again next day to **2015-01-03 10:00**

Is there any way to update it automaticaly ?! if yes how is there any function daily ?

Thank you

Comment: If it's daily, why not just store the time?

Answer (score 0):

In general WordPress posts do not represent *continuous* process. They and their data capture the state of certain point in time (last edit).

While there is a WP Cron mechanism for scheduled and (optionally) recurrent operations, it's poorly suited for periodic post manipulation. For a large amounts of posts it would take either excessively long running update routines, or excessive amount of short running but multiple events firing. Either has issues.

In a nutshell I would suggest instead of looking *how to* do this, you should look *how **not** to*. As comment suggests there might be easier to change what data precisely you store and work with it, than make recurrent changes to it.